# Selecionar cidades com mesmo nome em estados diferentes

Tags: sql, oracle, pl-sql

Tenho a tabela (resultado de uma consulta) com as cidades e seu respectivo estado...

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

... agora falta exibir apenas as cidades com nomes iguais e estados diferentes:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como faço o comando?

Comment: Qual a capital de Beneficiário Reabilitado ? Quem é o governador ? ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seria mais ou menos algo assim, primeiro você pega so as que possuem mais de uma recorrência na tabela, e depois faz uma query pelo nome, como não sabia o nome da sua tabela só substitua a tag `[sua_tabela]` pelo nome da tabela e teste:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM [sua_tabela]
WHERE cidade = (
SELECT
    cidade
FROM 
(SELECT 
    COUNT(*) AS qtd,
    cidade
from [sua_tabela]
GROUP BY cidade
HAVING qtd > 1) as aux);
```

Answer (score 0):

Achei estranho a resposta do arllondias já que não verifica ao menos os estados, acredito que desta forma seja mais correta:

```
    select  [Coluna da cidade]
    from    [Tabela]
    group by [Coluna da cidade]
    having count(distinct [Coluna de estado]) > 1
```

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).